# gactions cli account login and linking is failing

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to setup account linked to the cloud via 'gactions login' and I am encountering an error.  I cannot guess get past the proxy error shown below:

```
C:\code\ses\dashboard>gactions login
Gactions needs access to your Google account. Please copy & paste the URL below into a web browser and follow the instructions there. Then copy and paste the authorization code from the browser back here.
Visit this URL:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=619137215474-qf2rvbl5ne24t476dkc3gc3phlak4eg7.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Factions.builder&state=state
Enter authorization code:
returned_valid_token__from_website_Auth_entered_here
[ERROR] Post "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 23.221.222.250:8080: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I am on a corporate laptop with HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY cleared and VPN turned off.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am also getting this (if I go through VPN and corporate proxy) [ERROR] Post "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token": proxyconnect tcp: EOF

Answer (score 0):

This is an OAuth flow.

You are prompted to visit the URL (which you should do).

You will be prompted to login using a Google (Gmail) account.

When you do, you will be provided with a token that you copy into the `gactions login` command's prompt `Enter authorization code`.

This completes the flow and authenticates `gactions` with your Google (Gmail) account.

Comment: I've got that part and it should work, however, the 'proxyconnect' error above is preventing this.

Answer (score 0):

so it magically worked for me.  Not entirely sure why.

Using Windows' command terminal:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set HTTP_PROXY=

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set HTTPS_PROXY=

C:\WINDOWS\system32>gactions login
Gactions needs access to your Google account. Please copy & paste the URL below into a web browser and follow the instructions there. Then copy and paste the authorization code from the browser back here.
Visit this URL:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=619137215474-qf2rvbl5ne24t476dkc3gc3phlak4eg7.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Factions.builder&state=state
Enter authorization code:
4/1AY0e-g5rdKj1hoQfhFk--replacedToken
Done. Successfully logged in.
```